# How to check if webdriver is using default content or frame?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code:

```py
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("id")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
...
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Is there any way to verify, if i'm using frame or default content? The code is more complex and it would be really useful to have possibility to distinguish it.

Comment: I mean why do you wanna know that ? your program will only know what you feed to your program.

Comment: @cruisepandey I wrote decorator for Page Object Model's methods, that is using context manager that on enter is switching to frame and on exit is switching to default content. Some methods in POM are using other methods from the same POM that are decorated aswell. By having a possibility to check what's the "current state of frame", I could ensure that state

Comment: There's no way to know which frame you are in without tracking it yourself. What I usually do is perform some task and switch to the default frame so that I know where I'm at for the next method. Then the rest of the methods assume they are starting at the default frame.